# Length of stay in the Schengen area with a Turkish “special passport”

Tags: schengen, turkish-citizens

I have a Turkish “special passport” which exempts me from the requirement to hold a visa for the Schengen area.

My arrival date is: 13 June 2015, 11.00am
My departure date is: 10 September 2015, 11.55pm

Do these dates exceed the limit of stay in the Schengen area?

Comment: Where do you hold citizenship? What is the nature of this "special passport"? What dates does it say on your Schengen Visa?

Comment: I'm Turkish. It says 90 days in each 180 days. By the way, I don't have a "real" schengen visa. The EU does not require visa for special passport (green passport) and applies the schengen visa rules on it.

Comment: A visa is granted individually and materialised by a sticker in your passport. If I understand the situation correctly (I am not familiar with the Turkish “special passport”), what you have is the benefit of an exemption, not a visa.

Comment: So, is it "no more than 90 days" or "less than 90 days" ?

Comment: @Relaxed My understanding, though I don't have time to look it up right now, is that rules for special passports are set by each country, not by the Schengen regulations.  If that is true then the answer to the question depends on the details of the itinerary.

Comment: @phoog That's definitely the case for official (service/diplomatic) passports but I did not know this “special passport” until today so I have no idea. But whatever the rules actually are, “a passport that gives me a visa” made no sense at all, which is why I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

The visa requirement is created by a separate sub-paragraph in the relevant article of the Schengen Borders Code, which reads:

> 1. For intended stays on the territory of the Member States of a duration of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period […] the entry conditions for third-country nationals shall be the following:
>
> […]
>
> (b) they are in possession of a valid visa, if required pursuant to […]

There is no separate regulation, not even a distinct article, laying out entry conditions for “visa nationals”. To the extent that you are really exempted from the visa requirement, all the other rules should therefore still be exactly the same.

Regarding the maximum length of stay rule, see [How does the Schengen 90/180 rule work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule) According to the calculator mentioned there, your stay is exactly 90 days long so it should be allowed but you would not have even a single day left until December.

I must however add that any visa exemption for special passports would have to result from some other agreement or national rules (as pointed out in the comments by @phoog) and it's possible those rules would also create an unusual regime regarding the maximum stay for Turkish special passport holders. I don't really know about that.

(Yet another) EDIT: I am told that only some (but not all) Schengen countries grant Turkish special passport holders visa-free entry. I can't provide any details but you ought to double-check the rules for each country you want to visit because that's apparently not as easy as you thought.

Comment: +1, the so-called "special passport" is issued to former congressmen  and lower grade civil servants.  It bestows no diplomatic privileges or any other kind of privileges, but has somewhat greater mobility, like Schengen.  So your answer is fine, but please remove the last paragraph. The answer is whole without it.

Comment: @GayotFow Yes, I found a bit of info on this on Wikipedia, but still, what's the basis for this mobility? I don't want to give the impression I am an expert in all this and can positively confirm that there is a visa exemption or what the rules on maximum stay are because I haven't seen any authoritative source on this!